What is this science / tech TV show from around 2013?
I am trying to remember the name of a specific TV show that speculates about future technology and society. My web searches have mostly returned articles about times in the past when TV has correctly predicted the future.
What I remember:

It is a modern, recent TV show. Perhaps as old as 2008, but I believe it started more recently, probably 2013 or later.
In ads for it, a man talks about future advancements in technology and how there are good and bad consequences. I believe there are mentions of gene therapy, quantum computing, and others. There are animated visuals of a conveyor belt.
The show has a host / narrator, same person as in the ads.
One episode (I believe the first episode ever) takes a look at dating and predicts we will all have computer chips (wearables or brain implants?) that broadcast a profile of ourselves (favorite color, interests, etc.) and people will use augmented reality to scan people in a room with them. The show discusses the social implications of this. 
I remember the graphics being pretty decent or even good. It probably had a reasonable budget.


What country was it made in? What language? Where did you see it?

This description could be applied to any science vulgarization show, no?

Is it Popular Science's Future Of with Baratunde Thurston?

The answer turned out to be Futurescape. But in case it helps others doing web searches: I saw it in the United States and it is in English, And yes, the description is relatively generic. I added everything specific I could think of. I'm amazed that we figured it out. Thanks everyone.

The TV show is called FUTURESCAPE and is hosted by James Woods on SCI
http://www.sciencechannel.com/tv-shows/futurescape/videos/computer-chips-in-your-brain/

Futurescape was released in 2013
Narrator James Woods is seen walking on a conveyor belt. He narrates both the commercials and the show. He addresses the upside and downside of future technologies. Well known theoretical physicist Michio Kaku also makes frequent appearances as a consultant during the episodes.  
Episode 1 is titled "I Know What You're Thinking" and addresses – among other things – the ability to read eachothers minds (possibly addresses the computer chip dating you referenced). 
It covers many aspects of futuretech but seems to lean towards Biotech - human genome, bioprinting organs, connecting the brain directly to the internet,  bionic exoskeletons, longevity, etc.
The graphics were excellent, the subject matter intriguing and well-constructed. Nevertheless it only ran for 1 season and reruns no longer air on Science Channel.


May be you can add plot explaining how it matches with question. Link only answer are not much appreciated as this link me change in future

That was not a link only answer. Did you see the sentence above the link, or did your attention go just to the link?

I saw it and its one liner. You need to add more to answer like how it matched with description.

Tough to imagine how to answer the question any more clearly than the name of the show, the host's name and the channel it appears on.  But I'm open to suggestions.

You can mention when it was releaswd as it is part of question d. May describe first episode as asked in question.

Thank you so much! This answer is correct. It was very difficult to search for based on what I could remember, yet I enjoyed it and it felt memorable. I wish it was still on, definitely recommend it.
